# How to auto assign a foreign key?

Tags: c#, database, sqlite, dapper

I am using SQLite Browser and Dapper. How to auto assign a foreign key from one table to another? I am trying to save a course object's column into the `Course` table. And how to assign the `Course` table column `PersonID` to the `Person` table's column `Person ID`?

My thought was to pass in a `PersonModel` object and a `CourseModel` object and somehow use the execute method to assign the `course.PersonID` column. But I can't get it to work.

```
internal class Program
{
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        PersonModel person = new PersonModel("Jeff");
        CourseModel course = new CourseModel("History");

        DBAccess.SavePerson(person);
        DBAccess.AddCourse(person, course);

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}

public class PersonModel
{
    public int PersonID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public PersonModel(string name)
    {
        Name = name;
    }
}

public class CourseModel
{
    public int CourseID { get; set; }
    public string CourseName { get; set; }
    public int PersonID { get; set; }

    public CourseModel(string name)
    {
        CourseName = name;
    }
}

public class DBAccess
{
    public static string LoadConnectionString(string id = "Default")
    {
        return ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[id].ConnectionString;
    }

    public static void SavePerson(PersonModel person)
    {
        using (IDbConnection cnn = new SQLiteConnection(LoadConnectionString()))
        {
            cnn.Execute("insert into Person (Name) values (@Name)", person);
        }
    }

    public static void AddCourse(PersonModel person, CourseModel course)
    {
        // I want to log the vales of the course and somewhow assign the "person personid" to the "course personid" which is set as the foreign key in SQLite Browser.

        using (IDbConnection cnn = new SQLiteConnection(LoadConnectionString()))
        {
            cnn.Execute("insert into Course (CourseName) values (@CourseName)", course);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Should just be:

```
cnn.Execute("Insert into Course (CourseName, PersonId) values 
(@CourseName,@PersonId)", new { CourseName = course.CourseName, PersonId = 
person.PersonId)`
```

If Course has its person Id already populated, no need to send it through the method, just use it in the query above.

Comment: Setting a foreign key is just providing a value that exists in the primary keyed table.  So in this case, so long as you provide a person ID that exists in the person table, you will be fine.